# Returned variable is 'undefined' through javascript function

Tags: javascript, sql

I am having a little bit of trouble...
I am trying to get a lookup result as part of a web app, but struck-upon a little trouble.

I have a function that runs of a button click:

```
$(function() {
    $('#bnt_fund_8y').click(function() {
        console.log(dbCheck("study_mode"));
}
});
```

This dbCheck function goes away and check the local DB to see what study_mode is set, in the below function:

```
dbCheck = function(dbSearch) {
    mydb.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('SELECT "'+dbSearch+'" FROM funding WHERE id = 1',[], function(transaction, results) {
                var dbResult = results.rows.item(0).study_mode;
                alert(dbResult);
                return(dbResult);
            }, errorHandler);
        });
    }
```

The alert display the correct variable, but he console log displays undefined.
any help on this welcome...

Comment: That's an...interesting bracing style you've got there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`transaction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-database-transaction) is an *asynchronous* call, so your function returns (without returning any value) before the callback you give `transaction` occurs. The `return` statement in your code isn't returning anything out of `dbCheck`, but rather out of the callback function you've provided.

You'll need to change the function, and how you call it.

Function changes:

```
//  add callback parameter --v
dbCheck = function(dbSearch, callback) {
    mydb.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('SELECT "'+dbSearch+'" FROM funding WHERE id = 1',[], function(transaction, results) {
                var dbResult = results.rows.item(0).study_mode;
                alert(dbResult);
                // Call the callback with the result
                callback(dbResult);
            }, errorHandler);
        });
    }
```

Calling it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#bnt_fund_8y').click(function() {
        dbCheck("study_mode", function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbCheck = function(dbSearch) {
    mydb.transaction(
    ...
    );
}
```

does not return anything, so the value you get is `undefined`. As `transaction` seems to be an aynchronous call with callback functions, the only useful thing to return would be a promise for `dbResult`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything from the callback of an asynchronous call. Use a callback for the result also:

```
dbCheck = function(dbSearch, callback) {
  mydb.transaction(
    function(transaction) {
      transaction.executeSql('SELECT "'+dbSearch+'" FROM funding WHERE id = 1',[], function(transaction, results) {
        var dbResult = results.rows.item(0).study_mode;
        callback(dbResult);
      }, errorHandler);
    });
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
dbCheck("study_mode", function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell,

the function dbCheck isn't returning anything at all.

mydb.transactionis the function that is actually returning something.

As everyone else is pointing out, mydb.transactionis asynchronous.

You should just add

```
console.log(dbResult);
```

into the callback being passed into mydb.transaction